# How use $.when().then() when promise needs its returned data?

Tags: jquery

My apologies first if my question doesn't make sense.

I been running into race conditions and then went with promises, so far so good, but then i started getting another race condition happening again. I have 3 dropdowns being populated on the document.ready and I also have a function that populates a bunch of fields. So I tried reordering everything and that isn't working. So here is what I have

```
var orderStatusPromise = LoadOrderSummaryOrderStatus();

var jobTypePromise = LoadOrderSummaryJobType();

var leadSourcePromise = LoadOrderSummaryLeadSource();

orderStatusPromise.done(function (data) {
    ShowOrderSummaryOrderStatus(data);
});

jobTypePromise.done(function (data) {
    ShowOrderSummaryJobType(data);
});

leadSourcePromise.done(function (data) {
    ShowOrderSummaryLeadSource(data);
});
```

what I want to do is use a $.when().then() and put all the promises in the $.when() and in the .then() run the function that populates the fields, and that should finally rid me of the race conditions. 
The data in the .done(...) is being used to populate the dropdown.

Comment: Okay you have written what you want to do and it sounds solid. What keeps you from doing it?

Comment: @Tomalak, I think I got it figured out and working, but still getting race conditions happening

Comment: That's impossible to fix with the little context you have provided.

Comment: @Tomalak, Should I start a new question about the race conditions and provide all the necessary code or just bring up that I got it working and that I am still getting race conditions

Comment: If you ask me, this question here has little value without any extra information. Imagine being an uninvolved 3rd person trying to learn something from it. Up until now it's not even clear what the issue really is. Since nobody has answered yet you should flesh out this question until it contains enough information.

Comment: In other words, make an [mcve] that reproduces your race condition.

Comment: @Tomalak, I hear ya...this question was about how to add these types of promises into a $.when().$then(), I mentioned the race conditions because of why I was needing to place the promises as they were into the when()

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out on how to add the promises as I have them to a $.when().then() and what I needed to do was removed the semicolons from the .done() statements and replace them with commas

```
var orderStatusPromise = LoadOrderSummaryOrderStatus();

var jobTypePromise = LoadOrderSummaryJobType();

var leadSourcePromise = LoadOrderSummaryLeadSource();

var countiesPromise = LoadOrderSummaryCounties();

$.when(
    orderStatusPromise.done(function (data) {
        console.log("OrderStatus done");
        ShowOrderSummaryOrderStatus(data);
    }),

    jobTypePromise.done(function (data) {
        console.log("JobType done");
        ShowOrderSummaryJobType(data);
    }),

    leadSourcePromise.done(function (data) {
        console.log("OrderSummary done");
        ShowOrderSummaryLeadSource(data);
    }),

    countiesPromise.done(function (data) {
        console.log("Counties done");
        ShowOrderSummaryCounties(data);
    })
).then(
FillOrderSummaryCustomerFields(HomeStorage.Keys.OrderID));
```